# MapKit iPhone Development; Current Location and Annotations

Tags: xcode, ios4

To put it simply i'm creating an app that i want to display bars and restaurants as annotations on a map within a city but i would also like the app to show the user's current location. I need to know how to add multiple custom annotations easily but also show my current location. Can Anybody Help?

Here's a part of my ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];

 [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
 [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
 [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
 MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } }; 
 region.center.latitude = 53.793853;
 region.center.longitude = -1.752442;
 region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
 region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
 [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; 

 [mapView setDelegate:self];

 DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init]; 
 ann.title = @"Pashas";
 ann.subtitle = @"Leeds Road"; 
 ann.coordinate = region.center; 
 [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
}

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:

    (id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
 MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil; 
 if(annotation != mapView.userLocation) 
 {static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";  pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];if ( pinView == nil ) pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];

  pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed; 
  pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
  pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
  } 
 else {
  [mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"I am here"];
 }
```

return pinView;}

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the map view to show the user's location (it's not on by default).  Add this to the viewDidLoad:

```
[mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
```

Note that in the simulator, the "user location" is always Cupertino, CA so you might not see it depending on the map's current center and zoom.

Answer (score 1):

for showing the currentLocation use this

```
mapviewObject.showUserLocation = YES;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{

 MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } }; 
 region.center.latitude = 53.793853;
 region.center.longitude = -1.752442;
 region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
 region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
 [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; 

 [mapView setDelegate:self];

 DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init]; 
 ann.title = @"Pashas";
 ann.subtitle = @"Leeds Road"; 
 ann.coordinate = region.center; 
 [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
}
```